# Can I use a radio firmware for GB (2.3.6) for my SGS1 (GT-I9000) if I have ICS installed?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, cellular-radio, radio-firmware

I still have the original cellular radio firmware my phone came with (at least, I think I do. The baseband version is I9000BVJJPG).  However, I've changed ROMs many times, and am currently using the latest AOKP Milestone release.

Is it safe to install the latest radio image from http://samfirmware.com (PDA: I9000JIJVG, CSC: I9000CELJVG), if it is meant for 2.3.6, and I have ICS?

Comment: I'd guess yes in the case of a modem, but I don't really have anything to back that up.  I'd be even more inclined to say it wouldn't hurt anything to try, but again I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Judging from my experience: It's generally safe. Did that with 4 different Xperia models, my HTC desire and a Moto Defy+. I faced some of those problems: interrupted calls, wifi problems, crashes, low signal, higher battery drain, bad 3G/UMTS/... data service. There's no best desire radio (depends on carrier + your prefs: drain vs. reliability), Xperia Roms tend to depend on specific (not always latest) radios. **However**: By trial & error, nothing was permanently broken. had to reflash a known good one or find a working one. Not sure about Samsung phones tho, beware of the infamous brick bug

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it -- why would you want to install an other baseband? Generally spoken, it _should_ be safe to do so, but still I wouldn't do it without good reason (e.g. problems with GPS or WiFi, where a different baseband/radio image could help).

Comment: Izzy: seconded. Plus most if not all handset manufacturers don't release changelogs for that. Your Mod developer will tell you to update if it's needed as with 2011's Xperia line & ICS. forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to do that.

From my understanding, flashing an older radio than the one you currently have installed is a sure fire way to brick your phone.

Besides, the *latest* radios are *always* better. And so long as you are sticking with ICS, it is a *very* good idea to use the *latest* radio.

Like ce4 said, flash the radio recommended by whoever is making your ROM- 
And NEVER flash the same radio twice.